# rspec disable diff for failed eq

Tags: rspec, diff, equality, matcher

Is there a way to disable calculation of diff on failed `eq` matcher?

My code looks like this

```
object1 = MyCustomObject.new(param1)
object2 = MyCustomObject.new(param2)
expect(object1).to eq(object2)
```

If something wrong happened and those objects not equal

```
object1 == object2 # false
```

rspec trying to calculate diff, but my objects are very complex and this cause memory hog on my PC and Ubuntu just hangup. Really - I don't need this diff, so I just want to disable them. 
How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the workaround.
rspec uses `inspect` methods of custom objects to calculate diff listings.
So I create `insepct` in object and output not all stuff, that was automatically generated by ruby, but only that I really need in that diff - and it works.